# How to create multi row as header of Material UI Datatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

We are using Material UI and using `<MUIDataTable>` To display table.

We have multiple row as table header which is were we have to do colspan 2-3 columns also.

Looking for, How to customise table header column in a way that we can have multiple row as header.

I am new to React and Material UI, any hint or suggestions will also helpful.

Comment: I believe we cannot till this is open https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1248 , any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Might help others...

Using `customHeadRender` we can customize table header column.

[Here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-columns/index.js) is example.
I used two `div` in on column and added line between these `div`.

Limitations: In my case sorting and searching on these(customized header) column are not required so no need to write logic for this but after customisation need to think about these functionality provide my MUi-datatable.